# Why does my flexbox <a> grow to full width, whereas my flexbox button stays small?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I set `display: flex` on my `<a>`, it looks just like I want:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: white;
}

.firstchild {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.firstgrandchild {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <a class="container">
    <span class="first">
      <span class="firstchild">First - child</span>
    </span>
    <p class="second">Second</p>
  </a>
```

Turning on Firefox's flexbox highlighter shows that it renders like I want: two items separated by a small margin, and the container growing to the full width on the right side:

[image: The rendered elements highlighted using the flexbox highlighter]

However, if I now change the `<a>` to be a `<button>`, it suddenly collapses, and the first grand child breaks out of the first child:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background: white;
}

.firstchild {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.firstgrandchild {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <button class="container">
    <span class="firstchild">
      <span class="firstgrandchild">First child - first grand child</span>
    </span>
    <p class="secondchild">Second child</p>
  </button>
```

[image: The rendered button element highlighted using the flexbox highlighter]

Why does this happen? What styling do I need to add to the button to make it render the same as the anchor?

Comment: You can't. Follow the dupe link for answer.

Comment: You can, by wrapping your button in a flex div and adding `flex:1` to your button for example. Or you can just change it's `width`.

Comment: @LGSon Are you sure the duplicate is up to date ?

Comment: @Arkellys Yes, for browsers that replicate that behavior, for the rest it will render as expected. And wrapping it in a `div` doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks both. @Arkellys, I think the workaround mentioned there no longer works, but at least it's good to know that `<button>`s are not meant to be flex containers. I'll try it with your suggestions, or change the button to an `a[role="button"]`.

Comment: @Vincent And one more thing, it is not allowed to have a `p` as a child of a `button`, only _phrasing content_, like a `span`. Doing it could also render unexpected layout.

Comment: @LGSon Ah yes, I'm aware - this is the in-progress result of tinkering around :)